# How to create method that converts attribute's value to new value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, attributes

I have a form in which users input a number for the attribute :bytesize, which has an integer datatype. The number represents the amount of bytes for my object @catcher.

I'd like to have a method that will convert the value of :bytesize to megabytes. That is, I'd like to be able to run @catcher.mbsize, and that will display the number of megabytes for that object.

I'm pretty new to Rails, so my apologies if this seems obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion methods are pretty straight-forward:

```
class Catcher
  def mbsize
    self.bytesize / (1 << 20)
  end
end
```

Remember that attributes are internally stored as instance variables, so `attr_accessor :bytesize` is stored in `@bytesize`.

Comment: I did that, and it worked perfectly in my console. However, I want to display that quantity in my "Show" page, along with the other attributes. So, I used it as an interpolation in the partial for that page - that is, as `#{@catcher.mbsize}`. However, the error message "undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass"` came up after I did that. All of my other interpolations based off of attributes (such as `#{@catcher.bytesize}`) work perfectly fine in this partial, though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that `@catcher` in that particular case has `bytesize` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit enter before I finished, so I went back and edited it. Yes, it is defined.

Comment: When you said you had an "attribute", I construed that as an `attr_accessor` attribute, not an ActiveRecord attribute. I've adjusted my answer accordingly. `self.bytesize` will get you the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mbsize column to your db.

In controller:

```
def create
#other code
def mbsize
    @bytesize / (1 << 20)
  end
@catcher.mbsize=mbsize
@cather.save
end
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't need related DB record, you can simply define this method in Catcher model:

```
def mbsize
bytesize=self.bytesize
mbsize=#your method of converting
end
```

By some reason your bytesize is sting. You can convert it into integer by `.to_i` method

Comment: Why would you add a redundant column?

Comment: That works better, as it no longer says "nilClass" - now the error message reads `undefined method `/' for "12345678":String` . Again, I'm putting this into a partial, and I wonder if that has anything to do with it. The partial is set up as: `<%= " some code here...  #{@catcher.mbsize} and some more code like this #{@catcher.name} here " %>` Does that have anything to do with it? I do think it's notable it reads it as a string, if that has something to do with it. Again, everything else works except the mbsize method.

Comment: If it's not clear why it's doing this, it's possible I may have just messed up something else earlier on, as I'm new - and I can just mess around on my own until I figure out what. Thanks for all the help, both of you.